# Does CSS -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent; have accessibility implications?

Tags: css, accessibility, vendor-prefix

Does this CSS code have negative accessibility  implications?

```
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
```

I'm not an expert but I understand some people have difficulty seeing certain colors and I'm just bothered that if I remove the type highlight color it may affect them(I want to remove it because it makes the UI look weird when tapped).

I have committed to writing my web pages as accessible as possible so before I disable anything need to know the implications, and yes I'm new to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no accessibility requirements in [WCAG](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG21/) that require the use of `-webkit-tap-highlight-color`.

If you don't have `cursor:pointer` set, then you can remove `-webkit-tap-highlight-color` and it won't affect anything.

`-webkit-tap-highlight-color` is commonly used to override the default styles of webkit browsers (Chrome, Safari, Edge) when an element that has `cursor:pointer` is tapped from a mobile device.

The default behavior is that any element (or containing element) that has `cursor:pointer` explicitly set and is clicked will flash blue momentarily. You can bypass the entire issue by ensuring that `cursor:pointer` is not set.